# Drop 'NaN' value in set that is in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, set, nan

I have a dataframe that looks like this but with multiple rows:

```
    column_1         column_2         column_3
        1         {lk, 18m, NaN}    {kjaf, NaN}
```

I would like to take the `NaN` out of each set, but iterating through the rows results in `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`.

The code that I have used so far is as follows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    col2 = row['column_2']
    col3 = row['column_3']
    for x in col2:
        col2.discard('NaN')
    for y in col3:
        col3.discard('NaN')
```

Comment: Hi @Priya, could you post your code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if` in set comprehension if `NaN`s are missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': [1, 1], 
                   'column_2': [[np.nan, '18m'], ['lk', 'r']],
                   'column_3': [['kjaf'], ['ddd']]})

print (df)
   column_1    column_2 column_3
0         1  [nan, 18m]   [kjaf]
1         1     [lk, r]    [ddd]

cols = ['column_2', 'column_3']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: set([i for i in x if pd.notna(i)]))
#oldier pandas versions
#df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: set([i for i in x if pd.notnull(i)]))
print (df)

   column_1 column_2 column_3
0         1    {18m}   {kjaf}
1         1  {r, lk}    {ddd}
```

If `NaN`s are strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1': [1, 1], 
                   'column_2': [['NaN', '18m'], ['lk', 'r']],
                   'column_3': [['kjaf'], ['ddd']]})

print (df)
   column_1    column_2 column_3
0         1  [NaN, 18m]   [kjaf]
1         1     [lk, r]    [ddd]

cols = ['column_2', 'column_3']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: set([i for i in x if i != 'NaN']))
print (df)

   column_1 column_2 column_3
0         1    {18m}   {kjaf}
1         1  {r, lk}    {ddd}
```

Comment: Nothing happened when I did that

Comment: The NaNs must have been strings. The second one worked